# Malfunction indicator light after a charge to low battery

Tags: electrical, battery, battery-charger

My battery often needs a quick charge – 3 min or so – in the morning, then the car starts all day. Today, the light went on after the quick charge and would not go off after 2 blocks so I returned home.

Comment: You will need to get the fault codes read and then update your question.  There are usually local places that will read them for free.  You should be OK driving there if you don't drive the engine hard.  You are sure it is the MIL light, not the oil light?

Comment: Unless the check engine light is _flashing_, you should be able to continue driving without any problems until you can get it diagnosed and repaired.

Comment: Did you get your codes read?